# Does Adorner break MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, adorner

I'm developing a WPF app using MVVM. Most of my views have only xaml markup and nothing (except default boilerplate) on code behind.

All except one view that I use adorners to "blacken" the screen with when I want to disable the whole screen.

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //todo: transfer to modelview
        contentAreaAdorner = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(contentArea);
        waitingAdorner = new WaitingAdorner(contentArea);
    }
```

Is that ok? Or is there a better way to implement this in my viewmodel?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reducing code-behind is a *benefit* of MVVM, not the *goal*.

The purpose of MVVM is to make UI logic simpler and more testable.  Would your code be simpler and more testable if you moved this method to your view model?  Very probably not; in fact it might be less so.  So don't worry about it.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, but being new to MVVM I wanted some opinions first. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, any "purist" approach to any pattern will actually lead to more complexity and harder to understand and maintain code.

Comment: Should this read "application logic' instead of 'UI logic'? It may be confusing to readers would are not immediately familiar with the pattern.